# GoogleCast.framework v2.10 error

Tags: xcode, chromecast

I got this error when trying to update with the latest framework v2.10:

```
Frameworks/GoogleCast.framework: unsealed contents present in the root directory of an embedded framework
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

Any suggestions?

Edit:

This is iOS platform using latest version of Xcode v7.1.  The project uses Objective-C.  I just downloaded the 2.10 zip file from Google site and replaced a single GoogleCast.framework (from my current working project with older version of cast framework) file after unzipped.

I noticed 2.1 also came with "`CastFrameworkAssets.xcassets`" package.  The error I got will occur with or without including `CastFrameworkAssets.xcassets` in my project.

Comment: Can you give us a little more information about the context you're using it in - XCode version, whether you're using Cocoapods, type of project being built?

Comment: @IanBarber: I just added more information to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be a bug in the SDK. There is a GoogleCastResources.bundle in the root of the framework, rather than the Resources folder. Try moving that out of the framework root and into your app directly.